# laravel select all row from parent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, parent-child

I have table structure like this :

[image]

and for more description i also showing categories table :
[image]

this is my controller :

```
    public function kategori($id, $slug)
{
    $produks=Product::where('category_id', $id)->paginate(12);;

    return view('guest.daftarproduk')
          ->with('produks',$produks);

}
```

I can select all products from the child categories (id 43, 44, 45).

But i dont know how to select all products from parent categories (example id 42) while also fetching all product from it's child (id 43, 44, 45)

please help me.

--EDIT--- :

model :

```
public function childs() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Category','parent_id','id') ;
}
```

controller :

```
public function allkategori($id, $slug) {
    $category= Category::with('childs')->FindorFail($id);
    $child = $category->childs->pluck('id');

    $produks=Product::whereHas('featuredPhoto', function($query) { 
        $query->orderBy('photo', 'asc'); 
    })->where('category_id', $id)->get();

    return view('guest.daftarproduk')
          ->with('produks',$produks);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, get all child categories belonging to a parent category using eloquent, then loop through each of the child category in the returned collection to get the products.

Comment: i can get all the child id from the parent. but i dont know how to loop each of the child. can you give me example.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i found the answer with Has Many Through relation.

Model :

```
public function allProducts()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Product', 'App\Category', 'parent_id', 'category_id', 'id');
    }
```

Controller :

```
public function allkategori($id, $slug) {
    $category= Category::with('allProducts')->FindorFail($id);
    $child = $category->allProducts()->paginate(12);

    return view('guest.daftarproduk')
          ->with('produks',$child);
}
```